# read xml file using lxml get error EntityRef

Tags: python, lxml

i use lxml to read a xml file which has structure like bellow

```
    <domain>http://www.trademe.co.nz</domain>         
    <start>http://www.trademe.co.nz/Browse/CategoryAttributeSearchResults.aspx?search=1&cid=5748&sidebar=1&rptpath=350-5748-4233-&132=FLAT&134=&153=&29=&122=0&122=0&59=0&59=0&178=0&178=0&sidebarSearch_keypresses=0&sidebarSearch_suggested=0</start>
```

and my python code is:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('metaWeb.xml')
```

when i run it i get 
`entityref: expecting ';'` error

however, when i remove & symbol in xml file, everything is fine.

how can i solve that error?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this isn't valid XML. In XML, a `&` symbol always starts an [entity reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references), like `&#1234;` for the character `U+04D2` (aka `Ӓ`), `&quot;` for the character `"`, or some custom entity defined in your document/DTD/schema.*

If you want to put a literal `&` into a string, you have to replace it with something else, typically `&amp;`, which is a character entity reference for the ampersand character.

So, if you're sure there are no actual entity references in your document, just un-escaped ampersands, you can fix it pretty simply:

```
with open('metaWeb.xml') as f:
    xml = f.read().replace('&', '&amp;')
tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
```

However, a *better* solution, if possible, is to fix whatever program is generating this incorrect XML.

---

* This is slightly misleading quite true; a numeric character reference is not actually an entity reference. Also, a character entity reference like `&quot;` or `&amp;` is the same as any other reference with replacement text, the entities just happen to be implicitly defined by the XML/HTML base DTDs. But `lxml`, like most XML software, uses the term "entity reference" slightly more broadly than the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `&` with `&amp;` in your xml file, othewise your xml is not compliant to the XML  standard.